# How to find total work hours for certain period of time using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, datetime

I have a simple table query like bellow:

```
SELECT uid, dates, time_in, time_out,
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out)-TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))),'%H:%i') as 
total_wh FROM tb_attendance WHERE uid=10012 AND dates BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND
'2017-02-07' GROUP BY dates
```

That will output table like bellow:

```
uid     dates       time_in     time_out    work_hours
10012   2017-02-01  07:07:02    15:56:48    08:49
10012   2017-02-02  07:13:13    07:13:13    00:00
10012   2017-02-03  06:55:35    06:55:35    00:00
10012   2017-02-06  06:45:50    06:45:50    00:00
10012   2017-02-07  06:53:19    16:06:36    09:13
                 Grand Total                ?????
```

I need to find grand total for work hours in question marks using PHP. So far I've been trying these codes but it returns incorrect value.

```
`echo"<table><tr><td>uid</td><td>dates</td><td>time_in</td><td>time_out</td><td>work_hours</td></tr>";

$totalwh=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo"<tr><td>".$row['uid']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['dates']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['time_in']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['time_out']."</td>";
echo"<td>".$row['total_wh']."</td>";
echo"</tr>";

$workhours=explode(":",$row['total_wh']);

$totalwh+=$workhours[0]*60;
$totalwh+=$workhours[1];
$hours = $totalwh / 60;
$minutes = $totalwh % 60;

}

$x=date('H:i',strtotime("$hours:$minutes"));

echo"<tr><td colspan=4 align='center'>Grand Total </td><td>".$x."</td></tr>
</table>";
`
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend calculating the total time in seconds, then formatting the seconds into a date representation string. This formatting can be done with the functon **gmdate()**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

The time in seconds could either be fetched directly from the database using one of the query functions or the following could be done.

```
<?php

//Store total time in seconds
$totalTimeSeconds = 0;

//Loop over rows
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    //Output row

    //Split total working hours into hours and minutes
    $time = explode(":", $row['total_wh']);
    $timeHours = $time[0];
    $timeMinutes = $time[1];

    //Convert and add hours/minutes to total time 
    $totalTimeSeconds += ($timeHours * 60 * 60);
    $totalTimeSeconds += ($timeMinutes * 60);
}

//Output formatted total time in seconds
gmdate("H:i:s", $totalTimeSeconds);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: glad it helped, please mark my answer as correct. Thanks

Comment: @AhyasWidyatmaka If you like this solution, then ACCEPT IT. People spend time to help others, and to not accept their answer, is considered rude.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT uid, dates, time_in, time_out,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out)-TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as
total_wh FROM tb_attendance WHERE uid=10012 AND dates BETWEEN '2017-02-01' AND '2017-02-07' GROUP BY dates
```

Just replace

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out)-TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))),'%H:%i') as total_wh
```

with

```
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_out)-TIME_TO_SEC(time_in))) as total_wh
```

It gives output as

[image]
I thing it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You Change your code like this

```
     <?php
                echo "<table>
            <tr><td>uid</td>
                <td>dates</td>
                <td>time_in</td>
                <td>time_out</td>
                <td>work_hours</td></tr>";

                $totalwh=0;            
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                echo"<tr><td>".$row['uid']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$row['dates']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$row['time_in']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$row['time_out']."</td>";
                echo"<td>".$row['total_wh']."</td>";
                echo"</tr>";

                $time_arr[] = $row['total_wh'];

                }

                function explode_time($time) { //explode time and convert into seconds
            $time = explode(':', $time);
            $time = $time[0] * 3600 + $time[1] * 60;
            return $time;
    }

    function second_to_hhmm($time) { //convert seconds to hh:mm
            $hour = floor($time / 3600);
            $minute = strval(floor(($time % 3600) / 60));
            if ($minute == 0) {
                $minute = "00";
            } else {
                $minute = $minute;
            }
            $time = $hour . ":" . $minute;
            return $time;
    }

    $time = 0;
     foreach ($time_arr as $time_val) {
        $time +=explode_time($time_val); // this fucntion will convert all hh:mm to seconds
    }


 echo"<tr><td colspan=4 align='center'>Grand Total </td><td>".second_to_hhmm($time)."</td></tr>
                </table>";
                ?>
```